# setting LIMIT on subquery when amount of returned rows doesnt matter

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, innodb

im using a framework ORM to run my queries ... here is a example of ORM query output ... it is a  relational query

```
  select * from `clients` where exists 
  (select * from `transactions` where `clients`.`id` = `transactions`.`client_id`  )
  order by `id` desc limit 20 offset 02
```

i was wondering if putting limitation on subquery has any benefits performance wise in this query since it doesn't matter how many rows it returns

like

```
  (select * from `transactions` where `clients`.`id` = `transactions`.`client_id`  LIMIT 1 )
```

or performance in this scenario is not dependent on how many rows we select in subquery  ?

Comment: In your case `LIMIT 1` in the subquery doesn't change anything. But it could make sense if combined with OFFSET. `EXISTS (... LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2)` would mean "find all clients with at least 3 transactions". And it can be faster than to count all transactions for all clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where exists 
(select * from `transactions` where `clients`.`id` = `transactions`.`client_id`  )
```

The suquery is used as an argument for an `EXISTS` condition. In english, that would translate as : this customer has at least one transaction.

When processing this type of condition, MySQL generally optimizes the process to just check that at least one record is returned by the subquery. Using `LIMIT` in this context is useless, your RDBMS knows better.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is a fairly meaningless thing, because in your suggested subquery you are not telling MySQL *which* single record you want to retain.

Next, you absolutely *don't* want to potentially limit the exists subquery, because then you might cause it to fail prematurely, before giving it a chance to find a match.  The whole point of the exists subquery is to potentially scan the entire `transactions` table looking for a client match.

A positive `EXISTS` clause is already optimized in the sense that MySQL will stop as soon as it finds a single match.

Comment: A `LIMIT` without an `OFFSET` has no effect -- `EXISTS` stops when the first match is found.  Having `INDEX(client_id)` makes it quite fast -- no full table scan.